# What will flink do when zookeeper data reset?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zookeeper, flink-streaming

Our Flink uses Zookeeper as HA service. Therefore, Zookeeper continuously keeps and stores the snapshots of Flink data. (There is also Kafka connected to Zookeeper)

I am curious about if Zookeeper nodes are all reset and all snapshot data disappeared, what Flink will do next?

Comment: Should be able to easily test this yourself, no?

Answer (score 2):

Flink doesn't use Zookeeper for storing snapshots of Flink data. It uses Zookeeper to determine what is the active JobManager and if it should switch to another one, to achieve a high availability setup for Flink's JobManager.

Snapshots are written to a high available storage directory, like S3 or HDFS. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/ha/zookeeper_ha/

If the Zookeeper data is gone, it means that Flink doesn't know what's the currently active JobManager and therefore the cluster and its jobs will cancel.